# Django. Смена электронной почты пользователя через письмо

Tags: python, django

Необходимо сменить почту пользователя на сайте с помошью письма обратной связи. Смена почты происходит при клике на ссылке в письме.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, алгоритм смены почты, что должно приходить в письме пользователю и что происходит после перехода по ссылке в письме. Примеры кода или документацию, которые можно почитать.

Answer (score 1):

Советую посмотреть код в стандартном функционале восстановления забытого пароля у пользователя. Если мне не изменяет память шаги там следующие:

- пользователь заходит в форму забытого пароля ->
- вводит email
- если емейл существует, то
- сервер создает зашифрованый одноразовый токен
- отправляет его клиенту на указаный email в виде ссылки на специальную
  вьюху
- клиент заходит по ссылке
- если токен не был использован, то
- позволяет изменить пароль.

Подробнее в [документации Django Authentication Views¶](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views)